# Select Range up until specific string VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet that formats a report pulled externally from an application. Most of my formatting is done, but for one portion of it I just need to select all cells in range A9:I**Z** where Z is the number of rows up until a specific string (not including the string itself).

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1has9JKwbg3R52zVRpNGnsYPqhFwM0YH9t18-ADd0h9Q/edit?usp=sharing) is an example sheet. I need everything from A1:I649 selected, it's the row right above cell A650, which always has the string "***Total" in it. This report is dynamic, so changes length every day, but I formatted it so that ***Total always appears at the bottom. I just can't figure out how to select everything up until it for the next part of my script. I've already set up the rest of my code, I just need to nail this portion of it.

I made a shorthand image for a visual. In this case, I need A10:I30 to be my selected range, as it's the row right before ***Total

[image]

Just need it selected, because the rest of my script handles the rest of the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
dim rng as range, m as variant

with worksheets("sheet1")
    m = application.match("~*~*~*total", .range("I:I"), 0)
    if not iserror(m) then
        set rng = .range(.cells(9, "A"), .cells(m - 1, "I"))
        debug.print rng.address(0, 0)
        rng.select
    end if
end with
```

Note the escape characters (`~` or tilde) that are used to remove the wildcard characteristics of the asterisks.

Comment: Getting a Synthax compile error on the line: "rng select" 

I tried changing it to rng.select and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Tried debugging a little by commenting out the if and end if lines, I got a "Type Mismatch" error on the "set rng = .range(.cells(9, "A"), .cells(m - 1, "I"))" line. Also altered the "~*~*~*total" part into "~*~*~* Total" since I didn't account for the space originally. It still didn't select anything though.

Comment: Managed to solve it, but marking this as correct to close it out. Not sure why it didn't work, it looks pretty solid and a lot c leaner than what I came up with, but it just wasn't selecting anything at all. Thank you though, maybe it was something weird on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. It's probably a bit sloppy but it works:

```
Sub LeanCut()
Dim lrow As Long
'This part is finding the cell with "~~~ Total" and deleting it and everything below       
Cells.Find(What:="~*~*~* Total", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False).Activate
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
'This part just selects everything from A10:I (last row with data)
lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A10:I" & lrow).Select

End Sub
```

Like I said, it's a bit sloppy but I'm not the best with VBA by any means, and it does what I intended. Just makes ***Total into an empty row and selects everything that has values in it from A10 down.